# Conditional formatting line by line

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to format a column so that it highlights if a cell is different from the preceding column. For example, if A1 is £2.50 and B1 is £2.52 then B1 would go red. I know how to do it based on one specific cell but I can't make it check B2 against A2, B3 against A3, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Column B- go to Conditional Formatting- New rules- select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"- enter formula:

```
=$A1<>$B1
```

[image]

Comment: This is right, and the screenshot is helpful, but the concept isn't intuitive, which is why the question was asked. I've upvoted, but could you add a few words describing why or how this works, so that the asker/a reader can take something away from this answer that will help them next time more than just a bookmark to this page?

Comment: I select Column B means I need to formatting the Column B. Then the formula **=$A1<>$B1** this is means A1 value is not equal B1, and this like a sample for the whole Column A and B. As you can see I use $A1 and &B1, the symbol $ fixed Column A and B but not for Row, so for each row the formula will change based on Row. Hope my explain is helpful.

Comment: Thank you, that is great. You have saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to format one cell the way you want,
and then use the “Format Painter” to copy the formatting to the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

okay. You can do it the following way.

1. select B1, then go to conditional formatting -> highlight cells rules -> Greater than
2. on the left box type, =$A1
3. select the color format on the right to your liking
4. click ok
5. now select B1 again and move the cursor to the bottom right corner of the cell. the cursor should turn into a black +
6. then drag downwards to other B column cells.